# Subscription with ngx-stripe

Tags: angular, laravel, stripe-payments

Does someone know or have an of how explain me how does ngx-stripe works to make a subscription.

I try to make it with cURL but i can't.

I can make the token card but what's next?

I have mi frontend with Angular and my backend with laravel.

I undestand that I need to make the token, then the customer and at last the subscription. but I don't know how, I already read the docs but I'm still stuck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main steps for creating a subscription in Stripe are to:

1. Create a Stripe Customer (stripe/cashier)
2. Collect a Payment Method (ngx-stripe)
3. Save the Payment Method to the Customer (stripe/cashier)
4. Create a Subscription (stripe/cashier)

You would only be able to use ngx-stripe for the second step (collecting a payment method) and potentially for cases where the fourth step (creating a subscription) requires authentication due to SCA. To start, I would follow the ngx-stripe docs for creating a Token:

https://richnologies.gitbook.io/ngx-stripe/examples#create-token

But, instead of calling `this.stripeService.createToken`, I would instead call `this.stripeService.createPaymentMethod`:

```
    this.stripeService
      .createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card: this.card.element,
        billing_details: { name },
      })
      .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.paymentMethod) {
          // Send the payment method to your server
          console.log(result.paymentMethod.id);
        } else if (result.error) {
          // Error creating the token
          console.log(result.error.message);
        }
      });
```

PaymentMethods are Stripe's newer recommend path for collecting payment details.

After creating the PaymentMethod you would then need to send the PaymentMethod ID to your server. In your server, you would create a Customer and save the PaymentMethod to it:

*Using Stripe*

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

*Using Laravel Cashier*

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#adding-payment-methods

At this point you will have a Stripe Customer with a saved PaymentMethod. The last step would be to create a subscription for that Customer:

*Using Stripe*

- https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-subscription (third code block)

*Using Laravel Cashier*

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#creating-subscriptions

That's the gist!