# Angular Ngx Stripe error: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I cut and paste the [Ngx Stripe](https://docs.ngx-stripe.dev/examples) examples into my Angular project. I'm using Angular 13. I got this error:

```
Error: src/app/checkout/checkout.component.ts:22:77 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

22           return this.stripeService.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id })
```

Is this a `strict` mode error? Do I need to put in a return type `:any` on the function? I tried `session: any` but that didn't compile. The `.pipe` is confusing me where a return type would go.

Or is something else causing the error?

Here's my `checkout.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { StripeService } from 'ngx-stripe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html'
})
export class CheckoutComponent {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private stripeService: StripeService
  ) {}

  checkout() {
    // Check the server.js tab to see an example implementation
    this.http.post('/create-checkout-session', {})
      .pipe(
        switchMap(session => {
          return this.stripeService.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id })
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, you should display the localized error message to your
        // customer using `error.message`.
        if (result.error) {
          alert(result.error.message);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Here's my `app.module.ts`:

```js
// Angular
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Material
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';

// Made by me
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FunctionsService } from './home/functions.service';
import { AboutMaggieComponent } from './about-maggie/about-maggie.component';
import { AboutKabbalahComponent } from './about-kabbalah/about-kabbalah.component';
import { DonateComponent } from './donate/donate.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout/checkout.component';

// 3rd party
import { NgxStripeModule } from 'ngx-stripe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutMaggieComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutKabbalahComponent,
    DonateComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    CheckoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    NgxStripeModule.forRoot('pk_test_51HUwT...'),
  ],
  providers: [FunctionsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I installed `ngx-stripe` with `npm` and I see it in my project's Node modules. I haven't set up the backend server code.

Comment: Try adding `tap` in your pipe and see what's the value of `session`

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have exact problem

Comment: If you still looking - this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774556/subscription-with-ngx-stripe Also, this documentation is great, aiming for angular https://docs.ngx-stripe.dev/core-concepts/checkout

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because TypeScript strictly checks the Object type (what it assumes `session` will be) and it doesn't find an 'id' property.

However, we can assume that `session` will have an `id` property when the response is sent as [we are following the official ngx-stripe docs](https://ngx-stripe.dev/docs/checkout).

To get rid of this error, you can assign the `any` type to the `session`:

```
// Check the server.js tab to see an example implementation
this.http.post('/create-checkout-session', {})
  .pipe(
    switchMap((session: any) => {
      return this.stripeService.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id })
    })
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
    // error, you should display the localized error message to your
    // customer using `error.message`.
    if (result.error) {
      alert(result.error.message);
    }
  });
```